# Powershell "ExternalEmailAddress can not convert the system.collection.arraylist

Tags: powershell, email, contacts

### My Goal:

To create in bulk Mail Contact using Powershell.
My program asks me to input manually the ExternalEmailAddres.
When I do so, the program works.
I can not do that because of the big number of Mail contact to create.

I just do not know see where my error is.
Anyone can help? Please.

### My code:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xxx.yyy.com/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$User = Import-CSV C:\CREATE-MAIL-CONTACT.csv
$Params = @{
    Name = $user.Name
    ExternalEmailAddress = $User.PrimarySmtpAddress
    OrganizationalUnit = "OU=Mail Contacts,DC=xxx,DC=com"
  }
New-MailContact @Params

My CSV:
------
Displayname Name        PrimarySmtpAddress
John Smith  John Smith  john.smith@abc.com
```

Comment: You need to loop over `$user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is missing is to iterate over each row of your CSV, one way to do that is with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
Import-CSV C:\CREATE-MAIL-CONTACT.csv | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $Params = @{
            Name                 = $_.Name
            ExternalEmailAddress = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
            OrganizationalUnit   = "OU=Mail Contacts,DC=xxx,DC=com"
        }
        New-MailContact @Params
    }
    catch {
        # error handling here
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```